# How to group by two fields and order by datetime?

Tags: python, list, date

I list made of sub lists with three elements in each.

```
 ['1', '10', '2017-05-05']
 ['1', '10', '2017-07-20']
 ['2', '15', '2017-12-12']
 ['2', '15', '2018-01-24']
 ['1', '11', '2017-05-15']
 ['1', '11', '2017-07-21']
 ['2', '16', '2018-01-24']
 ['2', '16', '2018-01-28']
```

I would like to do a group by on the first 2 elements and then return the list that has the greater date (meaning closer to today). so i would want the output to be:

```
 ['1', '10', '2017-07-20']
 ['2', '15', '2018-01-24']
 ['1', '11', '2017-07-21']
 ['2', '16', '2018-01-28']
```

The first 2 rows are grouped together and then the 2017-07-20 wins because it is greater than 2017-05-05.

Comment: Accept pandas' solution ?

Comment: The recipe: `sort` by the field you want to group by, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), then sort each group by date and pick the top element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` method from `itertools` library.

```
from itertools import groupby
for key, rows in groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
    dates = sorted([item[2] for item in list(rows)])
    print(list(key) + [dates[-1]])
```

Output

```
['1', '10', '2017-07-20']
['2', '15', '2018-01-24']
['1', '11', '2017-07-21']
['2', '16', '2018-01-28']
```

You can also use `list comprehension`.

```
list = [list(key) + [sorted([item[2] for item in list(rows)])[-1]] for key, rows in groupby(l, lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]
```

Comment: i swapped out list variable for my actual list variable, but i get a name 'l is not defined error?

Comment: @skim8201, l is initial list.

Comment: ah ok. for whatever reason when i get it to write. it cuts most of the output into single integers. 

['1', '10', '2'] 

for the first row?